# Restrict I/O Write usage using cgroups

Tags: linux, centos, io, cgroup, restrictions

I am trying to restrict I/O write usage on my server using cgroups.

Here is my partition table info:

```
major minor  #blocks  name    
   8        0   10485760 sda
   8        1    9437184 sda1
   8        2    1047552 sda2
```

Here is my Filesystem structure:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       8.9G  8.4G   37M 100% /
none           1004M     0 1004M   0% /dev/shm
```

Here is my cgroups configuration:

```
mount { 
    blkio = /cgroup/blkio;      
}

group test2 {
    blkio {
        blkio.throttle.write_iops_device="";
        blkio.throttle.read_iops_device="8:0 10485760";
        blkio.throttle.write_bps_device="";
        blkio.throttle.read_bps_device="8:0 10485760";
        blkio.weight="";
        blkio.weight_device="";
    }
}
```

When I execute the following read command, it restrict the read operation to use only 
10 B/s

```
dd if=file_1 of=/dev/zero
```

When I execute the following Write command, it is not restricting as per the configuration

```
dd of=file_1 if=/dev/zero
```

What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you're out of space...

Comment: Write operation is working fine, but it should not use more than 10 B/s but it uses around 70 to 80 B/s

Comment: But... You are out of disk space.

Comment: I have remove the some log files after that here is my new Filesystem structure: `Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       8.9G  1.1G  7.5G  12% /
none           1004M     0 1004M   0% /dev/shm` But still i cant restrict to Write I/O operation

Comment: @DivijSatra You are actually restricting the read stage to 10 **MB/s** not 10 *B/s*. Writing to `/dev/zero` is probably what leads to confusion about the transfer rate since dd compute this based on read and write rates and is not aware that the target file descriptor will discard the data behind the scenes, making the write operation to return very fast to the caller without actually writing any block.

Comment: Hi, Yes its 10 MB/s not 10 B/s. i have change the command .Now my dd command to `dd of=file_2 if=file_1 bs=24M count=100` so now reading and writing are from same account but write usage is not under the 10 MB/s here is the output of iotop command `Total DISK READ: 43.45 M/s | Total DISK WRITE: 113.88 M/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 1497 be/4 test2      43.45 M/s   47.53 M/s  0.00 % 84.64 % dd of=fil~ count=100
 1434 be/4 test2       0.00 B/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  0.00 % -bash`

Comment: @DivijSatra Do you actually add the command PID to group2 tasklist before the read/write operations take place ?

Comment: NO. Firstly there is no tasklist file there is only tasks file in that i cant write any thing. simply i just run the following command:`echo PID >  /cgroup/blkio/test2/tasks` i got the error like: `-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1):

You probably sorted it out by now, but according to [this blog post](https://andrestc.com/post/cgroups-io/) you need to tell `dd` to open the output file with O_DIRECT flag, otherwise caching kicks in and your cgroup config becomes useless:

```
dd of=file_1 if=/dev/zero oflag=direct
```